# How to find the longest side(distance from one point to another) in the Shape S of points in java?

Tags: java, logic

I'm just wondering how to implement a method that returns the longest distance between two connected points in a parameter shape?

```java
public double getLargestSide(Shape s) {
    // code here
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input and a sample output.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I figured it out on my own.